# Combine dictionaries in a list of dictionaries by name key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this

```
list = [
          {Name: Fred, Points: 1, Date: 1-20-2020},
          {Name: Fred, Points: 3, Date: 1-15-2020},
          {Name: Fred, Points: 5, Date: 1-13-2020},
       ]
```

How can I combine them by name to be this?

```
list = [{
           Name: Fred, Scores: [{
                                   Points: 1, Date: 1-20-2020,
                                   Points: 3, Date: 1-15-2020,
                                   Points: 5, Date: 1-13-2020
                               ]
           ]
```

I tried to create a list of names and then map the rest of the values back to the name, but that didn't work as expected.

```
names = []
for name in list:
    names.append(
        {
            'Name': name['Name']
        })

for name in list:
    for name in names:
        if name['Name'] == name['Name']:
            name['Scores'] = [
                {
                    'Date': name['Date'],
                    'FPTS': name['Points']
                }]
```

Comment: So you want to associate the name values with some of the original items (specifically, the ones that had that name key)? Hmm, what data structure, I wonder, is used to build associations like that? Could it be a `dict`? :)

Comment: `if name['Name'] == name['Name']:` does this line not seem suspicious to you?

Comment: Since dictionaries aren't ordered, how will one know which name is for which score?

Comment: @AnnZen He wants a separate dictionary for each name.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a built-in function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop should create an empty `Scores` list. Then the second list can append to the appropriate list.

You need to prevent adding the same name to the new list multiple times. In my code below I use a `set` to remember which names have already been added.

Also, don't use the same variable `name` in the nested loops in the second loop.

```
names = []
names_appended = set()
for name in list:
    if name['Name'] not in names_appended:
        names.append(
            {
                'Name': name['Name'],
                'Scores': []
            })
        names_appended.add(name['Name'])

for name in list:
    for name2 in names:
        if name['Name'] == name2['Name']:
            name2['Scores'].append({'Date': name['Date'], 'Points': name['Points']})
```

It would be much easier if your new structure were a dictionary that uses the name as the key, rather than a list of dictionaries. Then you wouldn't need the nested loop.